# Is it possible to connect to an SQL Server using Windows authentication with PHP on a Linux computer?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, authentication

I know it's a specific question but I'm really not sure wheter it's possible or not. With Wamp I can use the following code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "XXXX";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXX");

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn === false)
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Of course this code won't work on my ubuntu computer where Apache and PHP are running. Is there a way to specify the username and the password for the Windows authentication or do you have to use the SQL authentication ?

Comment: You might be able to fake it with a domain name.

Comment: @DanBracuk But no official way ?